# R merging several contingency tables into one

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, tapply

I have the following list of contingency tables

```
structure(list(`1` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = structure(list(
c("a", "b"), c("x", "y", "z")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table"), 
`2` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("b", "c"), c("y", "z")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")), .Names = c("1", "2"))
```

The list has 2 contingency tables and I want to merge them into one. I tried the solution out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030647/how-to-sum-counts-across-tables-that-may-contain-partially-different-categories) but it didn't work. It gave the following error

```
> tapply(T,names(T),sum)
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

The expected output is

```
> table(x[[1]],x[[2]])

   x y z
 a 1 1 1
 b 1 1 0
 c 0 1 1
```

Where `x` is

```
structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), upc = c("x","y", "z", "x", "y", "z", "y"), sfactor = c("1", "1", "1", "1","2", "2", "2")), .Names = c("id", "upc", "sfactor"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x25aa378>)
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your tables to long `data.frames` and then collect the counts:

```
xtabs(Freq ~ ., data=do.call(rbind, lapply(L, data.frame) ))

#    Var2
#Var1 x y z
#   a 1 1 1
#   b 1 1 0
#   c 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We may also use `dcast` with `fun.aggregate` as `sum` after `rbind`ing the `list` elements using `rbindlist`.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(rbindlist(lapply(L, as.data.frame)),
              Var1~Var2, value.var="Freq", sum)
#   Var1 x y z
#1:    a 1 1 1
#2:    b 1 1 0
#3:    c 0 1 1
```

If we don't want the "Var1" column, `acast` (from `reshape2`) can be used

```
library(reshape2)
acast(rbindlist(lapply(L, as.data.frame)), 
             Var1~Var2, value.var="Freq", sum)
#   x y z
# a 1 1 1
# b 1 1 0
# c 0 1 1
```